# Access instance variable values in array of objects: Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, instance-variables

I have an array of objects with one instance variable:

```
oranges_array = 
[#<Orange:0x007faade859ea0 @diameter=2.7>,
 #<Orange:0x007faade859ef0 @diameter=2.8>,
 #<Orange:0x007faade859f40 @diameter=2.6>]
```

For example, how would I access the diameter instance variables? I want to eventually get their average. Do I need to or am I on the right track in thinking I maybe use an each loop to shovel each diameter into its own array then use `inject`? Or is there a simpler way to access the diameter variables? Thanks!

Comment: I noticed you never accept the answers given to your questions. Make sure to go over your questions some time and accept the best answers given they solve your question. This way you let the community know, that the problem is solved and at the same time you reward the effort of the one, who has provided the solution

Comment: right.  Just going through my questions.  Sorry about that.  My love for this site has grown and I've learned better etiquette.  Now I'm just trying to go back and give credit where it is due!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to add `attr_reader` to `Orange` class:

```
class Orange
  attr_reader :diameter
end
```

Now you can get the avarage:

```
avg = oranges_array.map(&:diameter).inject(:+) / oranges_array.size.to_f
# with Ruby 2.4+ you can do the following:
# avg = oranges_array.sum(&:diameter) / oranges_array.size.to_f
```

Another option is to use [Object#`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) (without having to add the `attr_reader` to the class:

```
avg = oranges_array.map { |orange| orange.instance_variable_get(:@diameter) }.inject(:+) / oranges_array.size.to_f
```

## NOTE:

Using `instance_variable_get` for this task is the *last resort* option and I added it almost exclusively to show there's a way to get instance variables of objects in case there is, for example, no way to define attribute readers in the class.

Comment: Using `instance_variable_get` is a very rude thing to do from an object-oriented design perspective, you're messing around with another object's private data. The `attr_reader` approach here is the best, and really only way to solve this properly. The latter's a last-ditch emergency option.

Comment: @tadman posted it almost exclusively for showing alternative option (for example, if user does not have a chance to add `attr_reader` to `Orange`), but I agree that `instance_variable_get` is definitely not a way to go here..

Comment: Yeah, I agree, just flagging that in case people get *ideas*.

Comment: How can we check "oranges_array" carries array of objects?
Like oranges_array.is_a? like anything is there

Comment: @Ronats I don't understand what exactly you are trying to ask/do. Could you precise so I can try helping you out?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I have same kind of data like oranges_array above mentioned in the question. What I want is need to check its type like whether oranges_array stores an array or array of objects.  Is there is any methods to check for "array of object" like .is_a? which returns true or false.

Comment: @Ronats Sorry, I tried to understand but I just can't. I don't see what you mean by `whether oranges_array stores an array or array of objects`. `oranges_array.class` returns the class of the object, if it returns `Array` - you know it is an instance of `Array` class.